# Swift navigate back from view2 to view1

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have View1 in which button has title and I did successful segue to View2 with passing the Button title String which will be assigned to View 2 Button also.
Now when user go back from View2 to View1 , View1 Button has no value. How can I pass button value to View1?

I tried delegate method.. But no success :

**Edited**

**View1**

```
class PatientBreifInfoViewController: UIViewController, TasksViewDelegate {

    var passName: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var patientName: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        patientName.setTitle(passName, forState: .Normal)
    }

    func setName(name: String) {
        patientName.setTitle(name, forState: .Normal)
        print("View1")
        print(name)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if (segue.identifier == "toTasks") {
            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! TasksViewController
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.passName = passName
        }
    }

}
```

**View2**

```
protocol TasksViewDelegate: class {
    func setName(patientName: String)
}

class TasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var passName : String!

    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var patientName: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: TasksViewDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        patientName.setTitle(passName, forState: .Normal)
    }

    @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate!.setName(passName)
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: In the code you've posted `passName` is never set only declared. Do you ever give it a value. When you print name in `setName` what is the output?

Answer (score 2):

Your protocol and delegate should work fine. However, you implementation of `setName` in `ViewController1` is not using the `Name` parameter passed into it however:

```
func setName(Name: String) 
{

    passName = patientName

}
```

Should be changed to something like:

```
func setName(Name: String) 
{

    patientName = Name

}
```

You should also follow the swift naming convention of variables, parameters and functions starting with lowercase names and types beginning with uppercase names. So should be `setName(name: String)` not `setName(Name: String)` which would also mean changing `patientName = Name` to `patientName = name` in the example.

## Update

Because your view controller will stay in memory while `ViewController2` is on screen `viewDidLoad` will not get called again when transitioning from `ViewController2` to `ViewController1`. Instead, you can set the button's title directly in your delegate method. For example:

```
func setName(name: String)
{
    patientName.setTitle(name, forState: .Normal)
}
```

Comment: "you should mark you delegate as weak to prevent a retain cycle" ... This is generally true, but there's no real risk of the retain cycle, because when you dismiss VC2, the strong reference cycle is resolved. But there's no reason why VC2 should have a strong reference to its delegate, so your `weak` observation is nonetheless prudent. But your point about `setName` method is spot on!

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I guess I mark delegates as `weak` reflexively, but there's no parent-child relationship between these view controllers so there's no risk of a retain cycle. I updated my answer.

Comment: @beyowulf : Thats was silly mistake.. my bad!. I did change and as per Rob suggestion I did my delegate as weak, but still ViewController2 is not sending Name to ViewController1.

Comment: @Spurti have you tried placing a breakpoint or printing something in `ViewController1`'s implementation of `setName` to see if it's being called and what is being passed in.

Comment: @beyowulf displays correct Name in Print, But Button Title is still empty.

Comment: I am setting Button title in ViewDidLoad of View1  viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
             
        patientName.setTitle(passName, forState: .Normal)
        
        }

Comment: `viewDidLoad` only gets called once when you view controller is first initialized, not after popping back to it from a another view controller in a navigation stack. You can set the button's title directly in `setName`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @beyowulf I did tried to set title in setName function, Still its not working.

Comment: ´func setName(name: String) {
        patientName.setTitle(name, forState: .Normal)
        print("View1")
        print(name)
    }´

Comment: Perhaps you could post more code in your original question. It's a bit hard to follow. What is the name of the button in `ViewController1`, what is printed when `setName` is called, and what would you like to happen?

Comment: @beyowulf Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

[popViewController(animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621886-popviewcontroller) removes/pops current view controller from navigation stack. Now you can use first view controller of navigation stack to access its members. **You may not need to use delegate here**

Try this and see:

```
class TasksViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {



    @IBAction func backButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        if let pbiViewController = self.navigationController?.viewControllers.first as? PatientBreifInfoViewController {
             pbiViewController.passName = passName
        }

    }

}


class PatientBreifInfoViewController: UIViewController {
    var passName: String?
}
```